# Ignoring Less files with Middleman

Tags: middleman

I have a Middleman project that includes several Less files. I think Middleman attempts to build the files but fails. I can reproduce this on a a clean install. I just initiate a project, add an empty `'test.less'` within the source folder and then either build or run the server -- both fail. I get an error to the tune of: `cannot load such file -- less (LoadError)`

Is there a way to explicitly ignore these files?

Answer (score 0):

Middleman has support for ignoring files. The docs for this are part of the [dynamic pages](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/dynamic-pages/) feature.

In your config.rb you can call `ignore "test.less"` and this file will be ignored.

You can make this more complex by using globs or regexes e.g. `ignore "*.less"`. See the [ignore](https://www.relishapp.com/middleman/middleman-core/docs/ignoring-paths) docs for more detailed information.